# (LWC) Your company doesn't support the following file types: .csv

Tags: lightning-web-components, configuration, fileupload

This is in a Full Sandbox.

Been using an LWC which I created to accept a .csv file upload. It's been working for months with no issues. Today I went to test a new dataset and received the following error:

> Your company doesn't support the following file types: .csv

The code is as follows, but as I said, there has been no problem since it was built:

Code for file upload:

```
<template>
    <div class="file-upload-div">
        <h1 class="instruction-header">{uploadTitle}</h1>
        <lightning-file-upload
            name="fileUploader"
            accept=[.csv]
            record-id={myRecordId}
            onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
            multiple>
        </lightning-file-upload>
    </div>
</template>
```

The only suggestions I've seen are related to configuring the 'File Upload and Download Security' in Setup (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332030&type=1&mode=1). But .csv is allowed in this page.

Any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: Just want to confirm, this is in your production instance and not a preview sandbox?

Comment: Sorry for leaving that out. This is in a Full Sandbox.

Comment: Is there a reason your [.csv] is not ['.csv'] and have you tried specifying this as a variable in the controller instead of directly in markup (I don't know if that would make a difference, but a possibility)? Also, is the full sandbox on a preview instance - i.e is it a spring 21 instance?

Comment: So I realized the same thing. When I switched .csv to '.csv' in the markup, the compiler threw an error. So I moved it to the controller and deployed. That did the trick! So interesting that it worked for months prior to this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Good to know that worked! I have posted my comment as a proper answer in case you would like to vote it up and for an easy answer for anyone stumbling across this in the future.

Comment: Sounds good. I don't have enough rep to upvote lol

Answer (score 1):

Move the [.csv] to a variable in the controller, and then bind this variable to the property. Eg:

In markup:

```
accept={acceptableFileTypes}
```

In Controller:

```
acceptableFileTypes = ['.csv'];
```